# $\$9000$ is invested in a account offering $3\%$ per year, compounded continuously, how fast (in dollars/yr) is the balance growing after $4$ years?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, finance

> If $\$9000$ is invested in a savings account offering $3\%$ per year, compounded continuously, how fast (in dollars/yr) is the balance growing after $4$ years? (Round your answer to the nearest cent)

**My Answer :**
Using the formula for continuous compound interest we get the final amount, $$P_f = P_0 e^{rt} \\
              = 9000 \cdot e^{0.03 \times 4} \\
              = 10147.47$$

Therefore, the rate if growth is $= \frac{P_f - P_0}{t} = 286.86$.

My question is that I'm a bit confused about the term *"how fast (in dollars/yr) is the balance growing?"*. Did I get the meaning right in my answer?

Comment: (1) $3\%$ is equivalent to $0.03$.  (2) Are you open to a solution involving calculus?

Comment: @Anrdrew yes it was a typo, thank you. I think it's better to avoid calculus. But can you confirm that I got the meaning of the question right? I'm actually helping a student and I don't know what class he's on, so preferably let's just do it in regular methods.

Comment: @Andrew but for my understanding if you want to give a solution based on calculus then fine. I'm mainly concerned if I got the meaning right of *"how fast (in dollars/yr) is the balance growing?"*.

Comment: You have calculated the _average_ rate of growth over four years.  The question is likely asking for the _instantaneous_ rate of growth, which requires calculus for a full understanding.

Comment: @Andrew I understand. Then help me with your calculus approach.

Comment: How fast in dollars per _year_ at the four year mark? I would think that'd be the same as asking how much money you'd gain from year 4 to 5, which is $9000e^{0.03 \cdot 5}-9000e^{0.03 \cdot 4}=\$309.04$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a function $$f(t)=9000e^{0.03t}\implies f'(t)=270e^{0.03t}.$$
The instantaneous rate of change of this function at $t=4$ is evaluated by $$f'(4)=270e^{0.12}\approx304.42.$$

You can explore the difference between average and instantaneous rate of growth [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8vrwxxjb4m) (links to Desmos).

[image]

Here the black curve represents your function, the dashed line is the secant line representing the average rate of change for $t\in[0,4]$, and the red line is the tangent line, representing the instantaneous rate of change at exactly $t=4$.

Comment: In some answers available on the internet I've seen that they've done something like this : Effective rate of interest is $i=e^r-1$ and thus the balance after 4 years is $ = Pe^{it} = 9000 \cdot e^{0.030455×4} = 10165.97$. Thus the balance is growing at the rate of $0.03 \times 10165.97 = \$ 304.99/yr$. I'm really confused that why they are calculating the balance like this, and even the rate of growth like this. What should I do @Andrew??

Comment: I don't know the sources of these other answers you are quoting.